# Can't upload signed apk that targetSdkVersion is 30

Tags: android, android-11, targetsdkversion

I generated a signed apk with a target sdk version of 30. (Android 11). I know it wasn't officially released but my application is ready for the new changes. I am trying to upload it to the google play console but facing the error:

> You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about
> signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR:
> MIN_SIG_SCHEME_FOR_TARGET_SDK_NOT_MET: Target SDK version 30 requires
> a minimum of signature scheme v2; the APK is not signed with this or a
> later signature scheme.

**What I tried to do:**

1. I double checked that I selected v2 (Full APK Singature) when I generated the apk.
2. I tried to manually sign the apk using apksigner.

Nothing worked. I'm wondering if it's not working since the version wasn't released yet. However, I understand that it suppose to work from the documents.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? If yes please post the ans as i am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 81):

Short answer for those building Cordova projects on the command line: You'll need to switch from `jarsigner` to `apksigner` and set up the command accordingly. NOTE: You'll need to run `zipalign` *before* `apksigner`, which is different from how we used to use it with `jarsigner`. Here's an example:

```
cordova build android --release

zipalign -f 4 platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/myapp-release-unsigned.apk myapp.apk

apksigner sign --ks my-ks.keystore --ks-pass file:my-passfile.txt --v1-signing-enabled true --v2-signing-enabled true myapp.apk

... upload apk to store or whatever ...
```

Comment: Thank you! this solves the issue for cordova =)

Comment: This is the best solution for cordova. It worked fin for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Select both V1 and V2(Full Apk Signature) while generating the apk. This solved my issue which was similar to yours.

Comment: how to do that? can you help pls. I am using cordova CLI to generate the APK.. *cordova build android --release* am using this command.

Comment: @Utpal-UrBestPal See the answer that I added below https://stackoverflow.com/a/69473649/814416

Answer (score 7):

Generate an App Bundle instead of an APK.

In my app I targeted api 30 and published the bundle without problems.

Comment: This must be the right answer, much easier

Comment: LIFE SAVERRR thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I had a tough time solving that issue. The following helped me resolve it completely.

1. Add the following 2 lines in config.xml (root directory of the Cordova project)

> ```
> <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="30"/>
>
> <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="30"/>
> ```

2. Import your project in AndroidStudio
3. Under Build Click on Generate Signed Bundle / APK

[image]

4. Select Android App Bundle

[image]

5. Update Keystore file/password and all requested details (Please select the option of the export encrypted key, as you will require to upload this on the playstore)

[image]

6. Select Release

[image]

7. Before uploading the app bundle you need to upload the certificate (the one you download in step 4)

[image]

8. (optional step) You will also see an auto-generated **App signing key certificate** you can download that if you want
9. Upload the App Bundle & you can now release the App to PlayStore.