# How to add App signature scheme v2 to old apk

Tags: android

I have an apk using eclipse ADT and old keystore.
now app update on google play store requires using App Signature Scheme v2 and target API 30.

is there a way I can do to create a keystore signature scheme v2 file, without having to migrate my app from Eclipse ADT to Android Studio.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I am using this as a quick fix hack
after the zipalign step is done :

> zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk

I have followed this extra step:

> apksigner sign --ks app.keystore --v1-signing-enabled true --v2-signing-enabled true HelloWorld.apk

*Please note : use the same password you used for the keystore file.
So now you can upload your .apk file or .aab file to play store*

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63246656/cant-upload-signed-apk-that-targetsdkversion-is-30/69473649#69473649) I managed to sign my Eclipse Android project with signature scheme v2. I am running Eclipse under Ubuntu.

1. Right click on the project and select **Android Tools** -> **Export Unsigned Application Package...**
2. Specify the destination of the unsigned apk file.
3. In the console execute this: `zipalign -f 4 unsigned.apk signed.apk`
4. and this: `apksigner sign -ks path_to_keystore_file --v1-signing-enabled true --v2-signing-enabled true signed.apk`
5. Enter the password for the keystore.
6. Enter the password for the signer.

`zipalign` and `apksigner` I installed before with `sudo apt install zipalign apksigner`.

I am using Eclipse for Android Developers with version "Oxygen Release Milestone 2 (4.7.0 M2) Build id: 20160922-0846".

Answer (score 1):

After build for release -> jarsigner -> zipalign,
I just need these scripts. To sign the apk with APK Signature Scheme v2:

```
apksigner sign --ks yourkeystore.keystore yourapk.apk
```

To verify the signing

```
apksigner verify -v yourapk.apk
```